# Sunburst Diagram - Intelligent Hover Data - Plotly.express

Tags: python, sunburst-diagram, plotly-express

I was wondering whether there is an option to make the hover data on my plotly express sunburst diagram a bit more intelligent, and only display certain elements depending which segment my mouse is over. See the code I am using below to create the diagram:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'first_column':  ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5', 'value_6'],
    'second_column': ['North', 'East', 'South', 'West', 'North', 'North'],
    'third_column': [11, 1, 7, 9, 5, 2],
    'fourth_column':[9,9,7,6,5,4]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.sunburst(
    data_frame=df,
    path=["first_column", "second_column"],
    color = "first_column",
    values="third_column",
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Pastel,
    maxdepth=2,
    custom_data=['fourth_column'],
    hover_name="first_column",
    # hover_data={"fourth_column":True},
    template='ggplot2',
)

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=('<br><b>The third_column is</b>: %{value}<br>'+\
                            '<br><b>The third_column is</b>: %{customdata[0]}<br>'))

fig.show()
```

Is there a way for instance to stop the hover data displaying the custom data, if the mouse is over a certain segment? I.e. remove text where the pink squiggle is for certain segments of the sunburst?

[example sunburst diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJYhm.png)

Thanks for the help in advance.